# Boolean indexing to test class of objects in a series?

Tags: pandas

Is it possible to filter a series in a df by testing the object class?

I've tried:

```py
df[isinstance(df['A'],list)]
```

..but this doesn't work.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that storing lists in Series/DataFrames is generally not very efficient, and you lose a lot of the benefits of numpy/pandas. Would be interesting to see *why* you were doing this :)

Comment: mongodb is the data source. mongo doesn't flatten when retrieving sub-fields, so pulling data directly into a df like so:`df=pd.DataFrame(list(jobs.find({},{'id':1,'avgtime.overall':1})))` results in the avgtime series containing lists.  Using EdChum's help below, I was able to write a function to 'delistify' the series.

Comment: If you can return mongo query as a string, read_json can flatten subfields (and will be v efficient). I looked into this a while back but as wasn't using it for work didn't follow up... would be good to have direct mongo -> pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` and test your column like so:

```py
In [5]:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,'dsvfsdv', [1,2,3,4,5,], 3.4565, list('asdad')]})
df

Out[5]:

                 a
0                1
1          dsvfsdv
2  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
3           3.4565
4  [a, s, d, a, d]

[5 rows x 1 columns]

In [6]:

df.apply(lambda row: isinstance(row.a, list), axis=1)

Out[6]:

0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```

You can now use this as a mask:

```py
In [10]:

df[df.apply(lambda row: isinstance(row.a, list), axis=1)]

Out[10]:

                 a
2  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
4  [a, s, d, a, d]

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so.  Pretty sure you will need a loop and will have to run the isinstance test on each type in the list.  If the list is of objects and not specifically class's you will need to call getClass() for each element in the list for isinstance to work.